# How to import logistic_sgd

Tags: python, python-2.7, deep-learning, logistics

Now, I am using anaconda 2 and python 2.7 to try to complete an auto-encoder problem. The code on the internet requires "import logistic_sgd". However,  when I wrote "pip install logistic_sgd" in my cmd, I get:

could not find a version that satisfies the requirement logistic_sgd 
No matching distribution found for logistic_sgd

Can someone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

logistic_sgd.py is a file you need to download: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py

Comment: and after I downloaded, what to do next

Comment: In fact you need to download all the files in http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/ and save them in your working directory. Then execute your code in this directory.

Comment: thx a lot!!!!!!